# Visual Studio Manual Pages For C

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, manpage

What do windows developers do when they need to look up the man page for a typical C function ? For example, say I am writing some C code in Visual Studio and I need to remember the order of arguments and exact behavior of strcpy. Note that I am not looking to duplicate my Linux/OS X experience, rather to discover the easiest, most common way to obtain this information for a typical Windows developer.

Thanks.

Comment: I just do a quick google search.

Comment: `strcpy(` Ctrl-shift-space, pops up Intellisense showing the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

For that specific question, I would keep [this alphabetical list of functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/634ca0c2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) bookmarked. You can install this (and other VC++) documentation locally in VS as well.